# why the div didn't be center between two divs

Tags: html, css, center

I just start learning css and I want to make two divs on the edges and the div that have class called wide I want to center it so I give it position absolute                    and left:50% but it doesn't work

```css
.container{
    background-color:#6699;
    width: 900px;
    height:600px;
    margin:20px auto;
    position: relative
}

.tall{
    background-color:#993399;
    width: 200px;
    height:100%;
    float: right
}

.wide{
    background-color:#6600cc;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%
}


.tall2{
    background-color:#006699;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="float.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tall"></div>
        <div class="wide"></div>
        <div class="tall2"></div>
        
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I am assuming you want three columns, with the first and third columns taking up 25% of the width of the page each and the center column taking half of the page width? https://imgur.com/a/IZdiVSe

Answer (score 2):

It's not totally clear what you're trying to do, but most likely you would be better served by a `flex` or `grid` layout. Floats are generally not best practice anymore for layouts like this.

You could try something like this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.tall, .tall2 {
  width: 200px;
}

.wide {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to align the 'wide' div horizontally then add a transform to the div like this:

```
.wide{
    background-color:#6600cc;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;

    /* Over Here */
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done using the `display: table;`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` style.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #6699;
 width: 100%;
}

.tall {
  background-color: #993399;
}

.wide {
  background-color: #6600cc;
 width: auto;
}

.tall2 {
  background-color: #006699;
}

.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.tall,
.tall2 {
  width: 200px;
}

* {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="table container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell tall"></div>
      <div class="cell wide"></div>
      <div class="cell tall2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```